# Submit popup contact form without redirecting

Tags: javascript, html

How to submit a popup contact form without redirecting?

I want to do this:

1- Close the popup form after the user press the button submit.
2- After that show the alert message and the user will close it.
3- The user stays where he was before without refreshing the page.

**HTML**

```
<title>Popup contact form </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/elements.css" />
    <script src="js/my_js.js"></script> 

<div id ="bdy" onclick = "check(event)" style="overflow:hidden;">

 <div id="abc">
 <div id="popupContact"> 
        <form action="http://www.example.pt/cgi-bi/FormMail.pl" method="post" id="form" >
            <img src="images/3.png" id="close"/>
            <h2>Contact Us</h2><hr/>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>

            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>

            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" id="msg"></textarea>

            <a id="submit" href="javascript: check_empty()">Send</a>
        </form>
 </div> 
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
function check_empty(){
if(document.getElementById('name').value == "" 
|| document.getElementById('email').value == "" 
||document.getElementById('msg').value == "" ){
alert ("Fill the fields!");
}
    else {  
    document.getElementById('form').submit();  
    alert ("Thank you for your contact");
    }
}

//function to display Popup
function div_show(){ 
document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";
}

//function to check target element
function check(e){ 
var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement); 

var obj = document.getElementById('abc'); 
var obj2 = document.getElementById('popup'); 

checkParent(target)?obj.style.display='none':null; 
target==obj2?obj.style.display='block':null; 

} 

//function to check parent node and return result accordingly
function checkParent(t){ 
    while(t.parentNode){ 
        if(t==document.getElementById('abc'))
            { 
                return false 
            }
        else if(t==document.getElementById('close'))
            {
                return true
            } 
        t=t.parentNode 
    } 
    return true 
}
```

Comment: First you need to stop the request. So you will stay on the same page (done with `event.preventDefault()` ). Then you need to access every data you need to send and do an Ajax call with javascript

Comment: I think i did that. It is redirecting me to the form action after i press submit.

Comment: in your code, I don't see and AJAX call nor a preventdefault

Comment: I tested before i post the code but it didn´t work. Or maybe i did it wrong!?

Comment: I tried to stop the request with event.preventDefault() but it is always redirecting to the form action.

Comment: Just posted a response with some code. it could help you i think

Answer (score 0):

without the code I can be sure. But there is a link with and example. In your case, you should attach the event with the submit event.
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

There is an example with code:

```
var form = document.getElementsByClassName('form');
form[0].addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('event');
});
```

Comment: Thank you but it isn´t working.
Whatever i do it redirects me to the FormMail.pl "Thank You" page.